Improve an addition worksheet using xlop
I have the following worksheet,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xlop}
    
\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%

\newcounter{RandSeed}       
\setcounter{RandSeed}{6} % choose an integer random seed for this build of problems and answers <<<<<   

%%  \OneXLine{<true or false>}{<result color>}  
\newcommand{\OneXline}[2]{% one line of 8 problems, workings or answers
\hspace*{\fill}
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOnea} {\AddTwoa} \hfill
\opadd[carryadd=#1, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{#2}]{\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} 
\hspace*{\fill}\\
}

\newcommand{\GenerateRandom}{%  %   \GenerateRandom
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneb}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwob}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
}
    
%---------------------------------------% 
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{%

    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{% 
        \pgfmathsetseed{\i+\value{RandSeed}}
        \GenerateRandom
        \OneXline{false}{white}
        ~\newline
        ~\newline
    }
    
    \newpage% added <<<<<<<<<<      
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
        \pgfmathsetseed{\i+\value{RandSeed}}
        \GenerateRandom
        \OneXline{true}{white}  
        ~\newline
    }
    \newpage% added <<<<<<<<<<          
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
        \pgfmathsetseed{\i+\value{RandSeed}}
        \GenerateRandom
        \OneXline{true}{black}
        ~\newline
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \AddQuestion{1}     % number of lines of problems
\end{document}

is it possible using xlop to show the intermediate step on the second page? Instead of the second page just showing the carry, could it give the answer to the first addition and the carry and then have the third page as it is with the whole sum?
